# Create a gstreamer sink that appears in the list of audio devices on Windows

Tags: gstreamer, wasapi

I would like to write a gstreamer pipeline that mixes the audio from two sources. I then want to be able to select an audio source from an app on my computer, i.e. Discord, such that the mixed audio will play as if it was coming from my mic.

It seems simple enough to get the mixing right, but it seems like I need to use something like Virtual Audio Cable to achieve the second part. Is there a way to do this entirely in gstreamer or with something more lightweight than installing Virtual Audio Cable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no [yet] Windows API to create virtual audio endpoint, so that applications could interact with it similarly to real device. Consequently, there is no GStreamer wrapper over this non-existent API either.

Doing it without VAC would require that you still install an audio driver where you would provide your own endpoint for Windows to use and expose to applications.